# How to update user-defined roles in MongoDB 3.0 in a sharding environment?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-mms

I'm using MMS to manage my a typical sharding cluster with just one shard (at the moment): 3 mongod for shard000 (2 servers + 1 arbiter) + 1 config server + 2 mongos instances.

Auth is enabled and it's working well. I've added a user-defined role in the MMS admin console, and I can see it in mongo shell.

```
db.system.roles.findOne()
{
    "_id" : "admin.myrole",
    "role" : "myrole",
    "db" : "admin",
    "privileges" : [
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "",
                "collection" : ""
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeCustomData",
                "changePassword",
 ...
```

I want to change it to AnyAction on AnyResource (as [doEval](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval) action requires). So, I'm trying to execute this:

```
db.runCommand({ "updateRole": "myrole", "privileges": [  { resource: { anyResource: true}, actions: [ "anyAction" ] } ] }); db.system.roles.findOne()`
and for one second, I get the result I want:
{
    "_id" : "admin.myrole",
    "role" : "myrole",
    "db" : "admin",
    "privileges" : [
        {
            "resource" : {
                "anyResource" : true
            },
            "actions" : [
                "anyAction"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "roles" : [ ]
}
```

But, about two seconds later:
the role got restored:

```
configsvr> db.system.roles.findOne()
{
    "_id" : "admin.myrole",
    "role" : "myrole",
    "db" : "admin",
    "privileges" : [
        {
            "resource" : {
                "db" : "",
                "collection" : ""
            },
            "actions" : [
                "changeCustomData",
                "changePassword",

...
```

and I don't know "who" is restoring it.
I've tried the above commands from the PRIMARY and from CONFIG server in admin database.

How can I get the role stored?

P.S: I know that "eval" is deprecated in 3.0, but what I'm asking is the reason I can't update the role.

Comment: The MMS automation agent is restoring the role to be aligned with your config. Change the automation configuration.

Comment: Where should I change the automation configuration? "AnyAction on AnyResource" can't be configured through MMS GUI AFAIK.